# Where can I get the very latest version of Webstorm? (TypeScript debugging is broken in 11.0)

Tags: node.js, mongoose, typescript, webstorm

So I'm trying to write/debug some Mongoose code using TypeScript. Every time I run my tests, WebStorm throws a Java index-out-of-bounds exception. Apparently the issue will be addressed in WebStorm 11.0.2:

https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/475275;jsessionid=FA936C60140B6317E5D0D82514C7C93E?tstart=0

Is this version available to the public yet? If so, where?

(I would ask on that forum, but their login seems to be broken -- I can't get in with my WebStorm student account.)

Answer (score 0):

You are out of luck. Downgrading will more likely bring more problems and EAP (early access program; a dev version of an upcoming Webstorm that is quite stable typically) is closed now:

> WebStorm 11 EAP program is now closed. WebStorm 11 has been released and now available for download on our website.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP